# syncing Google spreadsheet and Google (my) Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, synchronization

I would like to synchronize a google spreadsheet with a map so that I don't have to upload everything everyday.

I found that it's possible to synch a google form to google map using Google Fusion.

See, [YouTube: Syncing Google Forms with Google Fusion Tables for Crowdsourced Maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxR4ZETbK3U).

But I couldn't replicate the process to my situation (I guess it's maybe because the spreadsheet content is not originated from a google form and maybe the script take that into account)

I don't know much about coding scripts but automating this process would be a blast for me!!

I hope someone will be able to help me out on this

thanks a lot and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

The only thing to account for this situation is the difference of form submit. The guy in the video sets up two triggers: one for onFormSubmit, and one hourly trigger for syncing whenever any manual changes are made.

I haven't looked directly over the code, but all you should have to do is modify the onFormSubmit code and trigger. Change the code to look for and update the fusion table with any new rows from your spreadsheet. And then change the trigger to your desired need, timer would probably be the best option. So every hour, or day, or run it manually after your done adding rows.

Now, if you were to edit the rows of data after they've already been updated, the hourly syncing will take care of those changes.

I could imagine that the hourly sync method could be changed in such a manner to look for rows that need to be added, could be as simple as calling the submit function.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer! I'll try to do that and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i could solve it.
A time trigger is not needed if you set the sync function at the end of the function OnFormSubmit (so "sync();" under "insertRowId(rowId, row);" Syncing takes place after each sending of the form automatically.
For larger forms I found out that you should not make a special column Location in the Fusion table. The address column should marked as Location in Fusion table. In the script properties of the spreadsheet give the addressColumn the value of the column title of the address column and the third property keeps unchanged ("latlng">Location. What happens is that the value of the adres is overwritten by "latlng". So if you have trouble to loose the original addresses, add a new column, copy by apps script the same address (that piece of script direct at the beginning of the function OnFormSubmit) and (after syncing) give the addressColumn the value of the column title and in the Fusion table marks the original addess column as Text and the new column as Location.